# Can you enforce a key on an object but let typescript deduce the type of Value?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I am trying to create an object where I would like to enforce the keys, but am happy to let typescript deduce the types of the values. 
A quick example is

```
const fooVals = {
  a: null,
  b: null,
  c: null,
  e: null,
}

type TfooVals = typeof fooVals
type JustKeysOfFooVals = { [key in keyof TfooVals]: any};

// TS deduces correct types of foo1Vals but does not let me know e is missing
const foo1Vals = {
  a: 'string',
  b: 10,
  c: Promise.resolve('string') , 
//  e: () => { console.log('bar') }
}

// lets me know 'e' is missing, but makes types any
const foo2Vals: JustKeysOfFooVals = {
  a: 'string',
  b: 10,
  c: Promise.resolve('string') , 
  e: () => { console.log('bar') }
}
```

[TSPlayground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=const%20fooVals%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20c%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%20%20e%3A%20null%2C%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20TfooVals%20%3D%20typeof%20fooVals%0D%0A%0D%0Atype%20JustKeysOfFooVals%20%3D%20%7B%20%5Bkey%20in%20keyof%20TfooVals%5D%3A%20any%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20deduces%20correct%20types%20of%20foo1Vals%20but%20does%20not%20let%20me%20know%20e%20is%20missing%0D%0Aconst%20foo1Vals%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20'string'%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%2010%2C%0D%0A%20%20c%3A%20Promise.resolve('string')%20%2C%20%0D%0A%2F%2F%20%20e%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log('bar')%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0A%2F%2F%20lets%20me%20know%20'e'%20is%20missing%2C%20but%20makes%20all%20types%20any%0D%0Aconst%20foo2Vals%3A%20JustKeysOfFooVals%20%3D%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20a%3A%20'string'%2C%0D%0A%20%20b%3A%2010%2C%0D%0A%20%20c%3A%20Promise.resolve('string')%20%2C%20%0D%0A%20%20e%3A%20()%20%3D%3E%20%7B%20console.log('bar')%20%7D%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20thisIsTypeAString%20%3D%20foo1Vals.a%0D%0Aconst%20thisIsTypeAny%20%3D%20foo2Vals.a):

Is this possible?

Comment: unknown type might be handy here

Comment: makes all the types unknown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd recommend using a generic helper function which constrains its input to a *subtype* of `JustKeysOfFooVals` and just returns its input without *widening* it:

```
const justKeysOfFooVals = <T extends JustKeysOfFooVals>(t: T)=>t;
```

You'd then use it like this:

```
const foo1Vals = justKeysOfFooVals({
  a: 'string',
  b: 10,
  c: Promise.resolve('string') , 
//  e: () => { console.log('bar') }
}); // error! property 'e' is missing

const foo2Vals = justKeysOfFooVals({
  a: 'string',
  b: 10,
  c: Promise.resolve('string') , 
  e: () => { console.log('bar') }
}); // okay
foo2Vals.e(); // okay
```

You get warned about missing keys and it doesn't forget about the value types.  Hope that helps; good luck!

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEA1AhgGwjAvDA3gKBhhQC4YwBXNNAGkJgCMzLq6jhmrb6BTT1-AF98+KAE8ADjxgAVBMnSYc4qSDjxEqDKMnSAUhWgBpHmIgB5OADFNi7HhgBtANamYASzAxXYtbPlaEAC6ZChgYoIA3CKgkLAAVoZQJmaWNgoY9gA8MjA8AB5QPGAAJpgGxqYW1rYYAHwAFFBkMgCUWHVQ0fix0BogAIyB9omVqTUZEA0ERKQwAOTQAE6eAObzbIxkAwAMmxwwAApLIAC27hA8AHRLPBAgaABuPA2LUCtg660wNDD4APT-Ih8GANb4dBy9B7XNAgVavBgoJbzb7CQStSIwQF5JYnJYAQhgEhOUiW4gWPHmHkw5wgEDWMXAfXkACZhjhRskqmlalMZsQyG8PutNkwYLt9mRjmcLtdbvcni8hWsUT8-sCyGDsHVIUzoVdYfD5ojkaihBisUCQM4UGJ8KzAlcXhbsdbbfggA)

---

Update: the helper function may disable [excess property checks](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/interfaces.html#excess-property-checks).  If you need those (and you might not, after all a value `{a: "a", b: "b"}` is a perfectly valid instance of type `{a: string}`), then you can use another generic constraint to simulate [exact types](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936):

```
type Exactly<T, U> = T & Record<Exclude<keyof U, keyof T>, never>;
const justKeysOfFooVals = <T extends Exactly<JustKeysOfFooVals, T>>(t: T)=>t;

const foo3Vals = justKeysOfFooVals({
  a: 'string',
  b: 10,
  c: Promise.resolve('string') , 
  e: () => { console.log('bar') },
  f: 1 // error!
}); // number is not assignable to never
```

[Link to code](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZiEA1AhgGwjAvDA3gKBhhQC4YwBXNNAGkJgCMzLq6jhmrb6BTT1-AF98+KAE8ADjxgAVBMnSYc4qSDjxEqDKMnSAUhWgBpHmIgB5OADFNi7HhgBtANamYASzAxXYtbPlaEAC6ZChgYoIA3CIq0gCiAB4owFBoYgA8MjQwAKoAfPYyMABkMABKPKAATgAm6YnAaBQ1POk+fjnZ7eoyedlgPABuPFV50aCQsABWhlAmZpY2Chj2mTA8CVA8YDWYicmpGQbGphbWthjZvXkAFFBkMgCUWHlQ0fgT0BogAMyB9jMTgtzssIDcCERSDAAOTQKqeADm0LYjDIAEYAAwojgwAAKVRAAFt3BAeAA6Ko8CAgNDDG6wqDwsBIx4wbK8Mg3VkvByfGnktAgBH0hgoKrQ1mCFFwdEwAD0cvWVQJVQAhEJHpF5YrKISGCMPJgwCBYCgIBB3AiwCgGGhpFAQOQhiN8EA)

Good luck again!

Comment: Yea, it does seem like this is the only way, although there should be another. Will open an issue